# Why does Z denote UTC in XML dates?

Tags: xml

As we all know, UTC XML dates are formatted like `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ`. But: why Z? What does it represent? Is it an abbreviation? Is it "because last letter of the alphabet"?

Comment: This has nothing to do with XML and everything to do with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z is the time zone identifier (UTC). It is also called Zulu time (Z: Zero hours), hence the Z at the end.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones

Comment: The question is not _what_ but _why_ ;) I.e. why not use "U" which would make more sense as it stands for "UTC".

Comment: Because it is also called Zulu time, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah, thanks, after adding that stuff about Zulu it makes sense.